# Rails localization syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization

I've installed Twitter Bootstrap into my project and found unknown syntax for me:

```
<%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize %>
<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
            new_article_path,
            :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

I can't understand the meaning of `'.title'`, `'.new'` and `'helpers.links.new'`. How do these constructions interact with the locale dictionary?

Also I've never met the construction `:default =>` in `t` method, where I can read about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

t is a helper method supplied by I18n internationalization mechanism of rails, and is a shortcut for I18n.translate method.

The locale file which I18n reads from is set by default to Rails.root/config/locales/en.yml assuming en is your default locale.

The first argument is the key which I18n will look for in your locale file.
The statement `t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new"))` means that I18n will look for the construct

```
en:
  new: "new string"
```

in your locale file.

:default is the string which will be returned in case the first key was not found.

`:default => t("helpers.links.new")` just means that I18n will look for the following construct in en.yml:

```
en:
  helpers:
    links:
      new: "new string"
```

and return it in case the first one was absent.

You can find [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.rb) the full documentation of I18n translate method.